# CollectionEditor yielding "Object does not match target type." for System.Drawing.Point

Tags: c#, collectioneditor

I have a custom control which has a property of type `Collection<System.Drawing.Point>`. When I use `CollectionEditor` to edit this property, the `CollectionEditor` window shows `"Object does not match target type."` for the `"X"` and `"Y"` properties. But if I use `System.Drawing.PointF` instead, there's no failure.

Can anyone please explain why this difference occurs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between Point and PointF lies indeed with PointConverter. Why this causes a problem is quite a long story, but at the end of the day it boils down to the following:

The `System.ComponentModel.ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor)` implementation in `System.ComponentModel.Design.CollectionEditor
.CollectionEditorCollectionForm.SelectionWrapper` simply returns `this`.

According to the MSDN page of the aforementioned method of the `ICustomTypeDescriptor` interface, an implementation should

> Return(s) an object that contains the property described by the specified property descriptor.

If I understand it correctly, in this case the implementation contradicts the documentation.

This is based on some research of my own, so don't take it for granted. I posted a report of this issue on Microsoft Connect, so hopefully we'll know for sure in a few days. I'll report back when an answer is received.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no .NET / C# expert, but the issue appears to be somewhere within the `PointConverter` class, which is used as the `TypeConverterAttribute` for the `System.Drawing.Point` class. The Collection Editor must be using something within the `PointConverter` class that fails.

I suspect `PointConverter` because the `PointF` class has no `TypeConverterAttribute`, and it works fine.

In the following example, which I cobbled together using some code from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx), your problem is seen when using the `Point` class in a collection, but not with the `MyPoint` class which is using a custom `TypeConverter`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Globalization;

namespace WindowsControlLibrary1
{
    public class MyTypeConverter : TypeConverter
    {
        // Overrides the CanConvertFrom method of TypeConverter.
        // The ITypeDescriptorContext interface provides the context for the
        // conversion. Typically, this interface is used at design time to 
        // provide information about the design-time container.
        public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
           Type sourceType)
        {

            if (sourceType == typeof(string))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
        }
        // Overrides the ConvertFrom method of TypeConverter.
        public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
           CultureInfo culture, object value)
        {
            if (value is string)
            {
                string[] v = ((string)value).Split(new char[] { ',' });
                return new MyPoint(int.Parse(v[0]), int.Parse(v[1]));
            }
            return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
        }
        // Overrides the ConvertTo method of TypeConverter.
        public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
           CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
        {
            if (destinationType == typeof(string))
            {
                return ((MyPoint)value).X + "," + ((MyPoint)value).Y;
            }
            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        }
    }

    [SerializableAttribute]
    [TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(MyTypeConverter))]
    public struct MyPoint
    {
        private int x;
        private int y;

        public MyPoint(int _x, int _y)
        {
            x = _x;
            y = _y;
        }

        public int X
        {
            get { return x; }
            set { x = value; }
        }
        public int Y
        {
            get { return y; }
            set { y = value; }
        }

    }

    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        private List<System.Drawing.Point> points;
        private List<System.Drawing.PointF> pointfs;
        private List<MyPoint> mypoints;


        public List<System.Drawing.Point> PointList
        {
            get{ return points;}
            set{ points = value;}
        }

        public List<System.Drawing.PointF> PointFList
        {
            get {return pointfs;}
            set{pointfs = value;}
        }

        public List<MyPoint> MyPointList
        {
            get { return mypoints; }
            set { mypoints = value; }
        }

        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bde. I find that if I make the TypeConverter.GetCreateInstanceSupported() return true. It will not function well

Comment: GetCreateInstance() returning true actually means that your type is immutable (or at least one of your properties is read-only), that is, a new instance needs to be created if you want to modify a property. Unfortunately this means that it cannot always be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is before you use collectioneditor to edit list(of point), use  `TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(GetType(Drawing.Point), New TypeConverterAttribute())` to set typeconverter of Point to nothing, and after that use `TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(GetType(Drawing.Point), New TypeConverterAttribute(GetType(PointConverter)))` to set typeconverter to default.