# Can't edit Point[] or List<Point> at design time

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, windows-forms-designer, design-time

I'm creating custom control that will draw shape from list (or array) of points.
I have basic drawing functionality done, but now I'm struggling with design-time support in Visual Studio.

I've created two properties:

```
private Point _point;
public Point Point
{
    get { return _point; }
    set { _point = value; }
}

private Point[] _points;
public Point[] Points
{
    get { return _points; }
    set { _points = value; }
}
```

As seen on screen below `Point` is editable, but editor for `Points` isn't working. For each property I get error `Object does not match target type.`

[image]

If I change `Point` to `MyPoint`(custom class with X,Y properties) editor works just fine, but I don't want to create unneeded extra class because editor does not work when it should.

My question is: Can I use array or list of point as public property and have design-time support for it?

Comment: The problem might be the collection editor confusing `point` for `pointf`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597737/collectioneditor-yielding-object-does-not-match-target-type-for-system-drawin

Comment: @TimothyGroote thanks for link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom collection editor deriving `CollectionEditor` and set `typeof(List<Point>)` as collection type, also register a new `TypeConverterAttribute` for `Point`:

```
// Add reference to System.Design
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;

public class MyPointCollectionEditor : CollectionEditor
{
    public MyPointCollectionEditor() : base(typeof(List<Point>)) { }
    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
        IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(Point), 
            new Attribute[] { new TypeConverterAttribute() });
        var result = base.EditValue(context, provider, value);
        TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(Point), 
            new Attribute[] { new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(PointConverter)) });
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then it's enough to register it as editor of your `List<Point>`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Design;

public class MyClass : Component
{
    public MyClass() { Points = new List<Point>(); }

    [Editor(typeof(MyPointCollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public List<Point> Points { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank You. This works fine. I have problem with `Designer.cs` file. After adding points they are visible in `Designer.cs` as `this.shape1.Points.Add(((System.Drawing.Point)(resources.GetObject("shape1.Points"))));` Can I change this, so that instead of resources I'll see values in Designer? Do I must create some sort of converter for it?

Comment: After closing the dialog  (after `EditValue`) set the converter to `PointConverter` again. I edited the post.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank You for help.

Answer (score 2):

If you can add a reference to `PresentationCore` and `WindowsBase`, you can utilize the [`System.Windows.Media.PointCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pointcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
private System.Windows.Media.PointCollection _points = new System.Windows.Media.PointCollection();
public System.Windows.Media.PointCollection Points
{
    get { return _points; }
    set { _points = value; }
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I'll leave this question open for some time. Your solution is an option, but requires two dependencies. I'd like to keep them as minimum as possible, so maybe there will be an option to use Point instead Points but using build in collections

Comment: @Misiu, no worries on leaving it open, I'd be curious if there's another way that doesn't involve a custom class or custom container as well. But out of curiosity, what version of the .NET framework are you targeting? `PresentationCore` and `WindowsBase` are part of the .NET framework since 3.0, so adding a reference to them isn't adding a dependency like adding a reference to the `XNA` framework would be .. ?