# Why doesn't Point[] work correctly in the winforms collection editor (via PropertyGrid)?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class with a public property for array of points

```
public System.Drawing.Point[] Points { get; set; }
```

I want user to be able to change this property using **PropertyGrid**.

Problem is that **PropertyGrid** allows me (user) to edit existing list of points.

[image]
But if I want to add or delete points then I need to click "..." button on the right side of the row and open **Point Collection Editor**.
[image]

I just don't understand why **Point Collection Editor** dialog shows me "Object does not match target type". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can I clarify? "Using struct as key in dictionary" - there doesn't seem to be a dictionary here, and you don't seem to be using anything as a key... is the real question here: "why doesn't a `Point[]` work correctly in the default winforms collection editor?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't edit Point\[\] or List<Point> at design time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561197/cant-edit-point-or-listpoint-at-design-time)

Comment: it looks like the existing post that @DeveloperExceptionError linked to is a perfect fit here